# How to pull information out of a 2d list read from a file

Tags: python, list

was given a file SalesData.txt to pull data from into a 2d list. I've gotten the data read from the file and put into the list and I can print the file to see in python. In the list there is a name followed by a number of sales, followed by another name and a number of sales, etc that continues for 6 people.

I don't understand how to pull each individual and their sales from the list and then calculate their total sales, commission and bonus.

I'm not posting code because i'm simply looking for a place to start with basic information, I don't want the work done for me. I just want something generic to kind of go on. I need to display it neatly in columns.

This code prints out the following from the file. I need to take the information from the file and calculate total sales, commission, and bonus. I could do this if I were creating the list out of my own chosen data, but doing it from a file completely throws me off and I don't understand what to do.

```
    def ReadTo2dList():
        infile = open('SalesData.txt', 'r')
        lines = [line.split() for line in infile]
        for lines in lines:
        print(lines)

    def main():
        ReadTo2dList()



    main()

    ['Yogi,', 'Bear']
    ['306.27']
    ['663.39']
    ['831.02']
    ['516.11']
    ['281.58']
    ['881.84']
    ['168.69']
    ['533.56']
    ['803.2']
    ['619.57']
    ['313.56']
    ['787.86']
    ['Gates,', 'William']
    ['440.32']
    ['278.51']
    ['509.75']
```

Here is an example of the file..

```
   Yogi, Bear
   306.27
   663.39
   831.02
   516.11
   281.58
   881.84
   168.69
   533.56
   803.2
   619.57
   313.56
   787.86
   Gates, William
   440.32
   278.51
   509.75
   967.44
   130.48
   823.05
   659.67
   705.68
   990.18
   401.28
   389.01
   742.74
```

Comment: `for lines in lines`? I believe you mean `for line in lines` then just `print(line)`

Comment: would you mind showing us your txt file so we can see how it's structured?

Comment: I posted a portion of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, you have the data pulled into an array `lines`. You can continue by looping over `lines` and looking for name values, and then begin collecting/summing/processing the following numerical values. When you find a name again, save the preceding name and numerical results to a new array, and start processing the next name. Make sense?